# How to handle long string where characters stick together

Tags: php, html, css, string, text

**String type 1**:he oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space     between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction

**String type 2:** asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd

[Example when only with string type 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dy24.png)

When I add string type 2 into the table the string will extend out from the the table

If I use css text-overflow to control the text:

[Here is with text-overflow css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szH5m.png)

My question is how can I have the string type 1 showing as the first image and string type 2 showing in text-overflow css

**Thanks your help in advance!!**

```
table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Rules</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    @foreach ($companyrule as $companyrules)
                    <tr class="bu">
                        <th><?php echo $i++; ?></th>
                        <th> {{ $companyrules->rules}}</div></th>
                    </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: add your css files

Comment: You can use this `table td, table th {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is check if the string is longer than a maximum length and contains no spaces. If so, echo out the `substr()` of the string and append some ellipses, otherwise echo out the entire string. Something like (untested):

```
$max_length = 20; // the maximum length of a string with no spaces

@foreach ($companyrule as $companyrules)
    <tr class="bu">
        <th><?php echo $i++; ?></th>

        <?php if ( strlen($companyrules->rules) > $max_length && (strpos($companyrules->rules, ' ') === false) {
             <th> {{ substr($companyrules->rules,0,$max_length )}}...</div></th>
        <?php } else { ?>
             <th> {{ $companyrules->rules}}</div></th>
        <?php } ?>

   </tr>
@endforeach
```

For the long string with no spaces, this would echo out:

> asdasdasdasdasdasda...

Comment: got it !! Thanks for your solution.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Let me know if you don't come right